# While loop that checks for an 8 digit binary number

Tags: java

I'm struggling to succesfully write this without errors. It for example i will type 101 and 103, but on the 3rd number if i type an 8 digit binary like 10101010 is still displays that it isnt binary. The while loop should check if the number is 1) binary and 2) 8 digits.

```
while (number.length() != 8)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)//for loop with accumulator
    {
        if (number.charAt(i) != 48 || number.charAt(i) != 49)
        {
            binaryfail = true;
            while (binaryfail == true)
            {
                System.out.println("The number you entered is not a binary number or 8 digits");
                number = Keyboard.nextLine();//re-entry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a loop to check every character. I would use `String.matches()` to test if the input is only 1's and 0's:

```
while (!number.matches("[01]{8}")) {
    // read number again
}
```

---

As an afterthought, if you wanted a *similar* solution that does *not* use regex:

```
while (number.length() != 8 || !number.replace("0", "").replace("1", "").isEmpty()) {
    // read number again
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! this seems so much more simpler

Comment: Though i have made the experience that loops are faster than regexpressions. It's a trade-off between clarity and speed.

Comment: @Gee858eeG The speed difference would be very small indeed. However you could speed it up by reusing the same `Pattern` (as a constant), though the code would not be as concise.

Answer (score 2):

Your Boolean condition is wrong, you need to check with `&&` instead of `||`

What you want to check is that the value of the character is different from 48 **and** 49. If you check with *or* then the result is always `true` because the character value cannot be both 48 and 49 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

i dont really get your question.

```
binaryfail = true;
     while (binaryfail == true){
          System.out.println("The number you entered is not a binary number or 8 digits");
     }
```

This has to result in an infinite loop, that shows that you havent entered a binary number

Answer (score -1):

Although there are better ways to do this, the following fixes your code with minimal changes:

```
String number;
Boolean binaryfail;
number Keyboard.nextline();

while (true)
{
    binaryfail = (number.length() != 8); // set "fail" flag to true if length is wrong

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length() && !binaryfail; i++) // loop - exit if fail
    {
        if (number.charAt(i) != 48 && number.charAt(i) != 49) // <<< note && not ||
        {
            binaryfail = true; // this causes the for loop to stop
        }
    }

    if (binaryfail == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The number you entered is not a binary number or 8 digits");
        number=Keyboard.nextline();  // so try again...
    }
    else break; // got here: so no failure - must have found a good number
}

System.out.println("Congratulations - " + number + " is an eight digit binary number");
```

Note - I updated this from my original post; this now works...